# How do I generate an upload key with android studio for mac?

Tags: android, keystore

While there are very detailed steps on how to generate an upload key for the windows version of android studio  - [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) - Using android studio artic fox for mac, I don't have the option to In the menu bar, click Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK. When I select Build I only have 4 options: 1) Make 2) Recompile 3) Analyze APK 4) Deploy Module to app Engine. Any thoughts?

The option appears on the project I created using android studio
[image]

but not the project i created using visual studio -

[image]

[image]

Comment: a screenshot will be good

Comment: post updated to include screenshots - 1) Generate Signed Bundle/APK is present but grayed out and 2) Generate Signed Bundle/APK is not listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to open  the android project not flutter goto tools->flutter->open for editing in android studio

then go for Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, Tools > Flutter >Open for editing isn't available in my version of android studio either.

Comment: Hi Omar - I was finally able to find the flutter > build apk option that you mentioned. thanks for your help.